# Simulating turtlebot hardware?

Tags: simulation, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey gang,

Is there some way with the Turtlebot packages to simulate the turtlebot inside of stage and/or gazebo? I'd like to be able to do some work while away from the office (where our turtlebot is located) and I need a way to simulate the bot itself. Preferably something that can simulate the Kinect as well.

I didn't see anything in the turtlebot tutorials on how to set this up. I'm still pretty new to ROS, so I've never used gazebo inside of ROS, but have experience with Player/Stage on it's own. I basically need help understanding how to set up and run the simulation and get a/the turtlebot model into it.

Any help is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11186/simulating-turtlebot-hardware?/) by [mkopack](https://answers.ros.org/users/1024/mkopack/) on ROS Answers with karma: 171 on 2011-09-12

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the next week or so we will be releasing a stable version of electric which has a stable simulation release. At that time you can sudo apt-get install ros-electric-turtlebot-simulator-desktop

this will install everything needed to simulate TurtleBot. To start the simulator

```
roslaunch turtlebot_simulator turtlebot_empty_world.launch
```

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2011-10-11**:
@mwise_wg On my (and my colleague's) environment (Ubuntu 11/10.04, electric), the command you're giving isn't working (rospack/stack either, although roscd works). Instead, this works "roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_empty_world.launch".